# Selenium python test hung up on url in cronjob

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python, chromedriver

My automated tests get hung up on the .get(url) command randomly.  I run several test suites everyday against 60+ different urls (each suite) and a handful will fail to get the url after initializing the browser.  The browser url will simply read:

```
data:;
```

Now if I start these tests from the command line and this happens, eventually the test will attempt to click a button that doesn't exist and the test will fail, the browser will close, and the tests will continue as normal. This is acceptable to me.

However, if I start the tests from a cronjob, the test will get hung up forever and stop executing - no more logs, no more tests, no more cpu usage.  This means that I cannot run the tests automatically which is an issue for me.

I've already attempted setting up 'retries' and starting the tests from a python script rather than bash script, which did not solve the issue.

Setup:

- Selenium 3.0.2
- Google Chrome 54
- Python 3.6
- Chromedriver 2.29 (and cannot switch to Firefox or any other browser)
- Kick off tests from bash script
- Run tests inside python's Unit Test and get url in setup

Here is an example test setup:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
self.driver.get(URL)
```

Thanks for your help.  I've navigated every webpage on the internet dealing with this issue and found no satisfactory conclusion.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm currently running into it on my end

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Chromium page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), the ChromeDriver 2.29 supports Chrome v56-58.

Probably, you will have to downgrade your ChromeDriver or upgrade the Chrome (the latter is better, in general).

[image]